# Capture first group in regex

Tags: regex

I have the following log line in a file

> 2017-09-20 11:52:00 | WARN | LEV-APPESB | 200 | 00:00:255 | nick |
>   test

I need to create a differents regex to extract each fields separated by pipes (|)
I seem to be on the right path with the folowing regex

```
^.*\|(.+?)\|.*$
```

the regex capture the string

> nick

which is last ocurence of my text separated by two pipes (|)

So here are my questions, what is the regex to use to :

- isolate the first column of my line (no pipe at the beginning)
- isolate 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th and 6th columns of my line which are all surrounded by pipes
- isolate last column (no pipe at the end)

---

**EDIT**

For your information, the regex is to be used in a log analysis system that allow custom field creation via regex. Split of the string via code is not an option here

Comment: which language are you using ? You can split by | and then strore the result in an array

Comment: You don't need regex for that, Just split it by **|**

Comment: Are you asking for separate regexes for each of the columns? I ask because I am used to making ONE regex with several capturings and then accessig them via e.g. `$1`, `$2`, ... It seems that you can only access a single capture group. Please confirm or contradict.

Comment: @Yunnosch yeah I'm looking for separated regex

Comment: `([^|]+)` should do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1

Use a non greedy operator: `/^(.*?)\|/`

### Question 2

Just capture each column: `/^(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|/`

The greedy version also works: `/^(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|/`

### Question 3

Just capture one more: `/.*\|(.*)$/`

I tested all three using perl:

```
#!/bin/perl
$str = "2017-09-20 11:52:00 | WARN | LEV-APPESB | 200 | 00:00:255 | nick | test";
$str =~ /^(.*?)\|/;
print "Column 1: ".$1."\n\n";

$str =~ /^(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|(.*?)\|/;
print "Column 1: ".$1."\n";
print "Column 2: ".$2."\n";
print "Column 3: ".$3."\n";
print "Column 4: ".$4."\n";
print "Column 5: ".$5."\n";
print "Column 6: ".$6."\n\n";


$str =~ /^(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|/;
print "Column 1: ".$1."\n";
print "Column 2: ".$2."\n";
print "Column 3: ".$3."\n";
print "Column 4: ".$4."\n";
print "Column 5: ".$5."\n";
print "Column 6: ".$6."\n\n";

$str =~ /^(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)\|(.*)$/;
print "Column 1: ".$1."\n";
print "Column 2: ".$2."\n";
print "Column 3: ".$3."\n";
print "Column 4: ".$4."\n";
print "Column 5: ".$5."\n";
print "Column 6: ".$6."\n";
print "Column 7: ".$7."\n\n";


$str =~ /.*\|(.*)$/;
print "Column 7: ".$1."\n";
```

The ouput of this program is:

```
Column 1: 2017-09-20 11:52:00

Column 1: 2017-09-20 11:52:00
Column 2:  WARN
Column 3:  LEV-APPESB
Column 4:  200
Column 5:  00:00:255
Column 6:  nick

Column 1: 2017-09-20 11:52:00
Column 2:  WARN
Column 3:  LEV-APPESB
Column 4:  200
Column 5:  00:00:255
Column 6:  nick

Column 1: 2017-09-20 11:52:00
Column 2:  WARN
Column 3:  LEV-APPESB
Column 4:  200
Column 5:  00:00:255
Column 6:  nick
Column 7:  test

Column 7:  test
```

Comment: According to comment, OP explicitly wants (though not giving reasons) one regex for each part, with only one capture each.

Comment: That is just a matter of removing all parenthesis except the one you want.